# Change “New Game Plus” tier in Torchlight 2

Tags: torchlight-2

Currently I am in a “New Game Plus” mode in Torchlight 2. But I want to change back to normal game mode. Is there a way to do this? Could also be a mod. I just want a functionality, like in Diablo 2 where you can change your game mode. Does anybody know if there is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Torchlight 2 Rapid Respec](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=43248&hilit=rapid+respec) external program which is basically a save / build editor that lets you change the New Game + level, among other things.